# FB SDK v2.8 doesn't show email

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using FB SDK v2.8. What I tried doesn't show user's email. It doesn't matter if I log in with my mobile phone, or email address. How can I get the user's email?

In my fb app dashboard, I can see email permission in approved items section

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large"
    data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId : 'app_id',
        cookie : true,
        xfbml : true,
        version : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
     .... 
  } else if(response.status === 'not_authorized'( {
     .... }
    else {
     ... }
});
function getCurrentUserInfo() {
        FB.api("/me", {
            locale : 'en_US',
            fields : 'name, email, gender, birthday, currency, website'
        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.name + ': ' + response.email);
        }
    });
```

[image: approved_items]
[image]

- It's weird to see a downvote with no explanation.

Comment: Where is the login part, where you ask the user for the necessary permission?

Comment: Once user clicks login button, it opens fb login page then if credentials correct, a popup appears and asks for permissions.

Comment: You are not asking for any permissions on that login button you have shown.

Comment: What should I do to ask permissions then?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Answer (score 1):

You are asking only for the default `public_profile` permission, you have to ask the email permission also.

Check the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/permissions)

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
}, {scope: 'email'});
```